# Directives & Controllers: resolve, loading, reloading

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I need a code for the next problem. I know which components (`$http`, `$q`, etc.) I have to use. I don't know how to do it in a right way! So,

1. I need an AngularJS directive or controller,
2. It loads some data via *several* `$http` requests,
3. It shows it,
4. It updates data (and re-shows it) every second,
5. The view has to be unchanged while data is loading/reloading.

Thanks!

Comment: Based on what you mention, I would look at these services: $http, $q, and $timeout, and create a service with these that updates your scope at a timed interval within your Controller. Based on your description here, I don't think you need a directive.

Comment: @koolunix Thanks for response! I know what I have to look for but I don't know how to summarize it in a correct way. I need for a more deep answer. And why not directives?

Comment: A directive is used when you want to alter the DOM, like show/hide, popups, modals, autocomplete. As I understand it, you want to update your model as seen on your view. Unless you are doing some DOM manipulation when you display your data, that's just simple data binding that can be done in the controller

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding with definite answers. Discussions about high-level design concepts and best practices are more appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com. Please read this for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82990/228805

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crate a Service to get $http resources and use $

Comment: I need a code! I know which components I have to use. I don't know how to do it in a **right way**.